# Smartface play video

Tags: smartface.io

I added video component to page then after I wrote this code as follows. But not working. How can I run this?

```js
Pages.Page1.Video1.playVideo(true, true, function() {
    alert("playybackStarrted.")
}, function() {
    alert("video Initialized.")
}, function() {
    alert("playyback Completed.")
}, function() {
    alert("Error")
});
```

---

I tried this. I defined contentUrl as video.mp4. But I can't run this.

```js
var video1 = new SMF.UI.Video({
        top : "10%",
        left : "10%",
        width : "80%",
        height : "40%",
        controlStyle : SMF.UI.VideoControlStyle.embedded,
        contentUrl : "video.mp4"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I added video dynamically and it runs fine as follows:

```
 var video1 = new SMF.UI.Video({
        top : "10%",
        left : "10%",
        width : "80%",
        height : "40%",
        controlStyle : SMF.UI.VideoControlStyle.embedded,
        contentUrl : "..."
    });
Pages.Page1.add(video1);
var btnPlay = new SMF.UI.TextButton({
        top : '52%',
        left : '10%',
        width : "80%",
        height : "10%",
        text : "Play Video",
        onPressed : function (e) {
            video1.playVideo(true, true, function () {
                alert("playybackStarrted.")
            }, function () {
                alert("video Initialized.")
            }, function () {
                alert("playyback Completed.")
            }, function () {
                alert("Error")
            });
        }
    });
Pages.Page1.add(btnPlay);
```

Comment: I tried this. I defined contentUrl as video.mp4. But I can't run this.

Comment: Where did you put your video?

Comment: I put to directory "resources/videos". So I want to local source. How can I do this?

Comment: If I give video link to contentUrl it works fine.iOS only support mv4 file, android is depends on device.But now it is a bug, it doesn't work if you put it under resources.You should give url.